# Using Once And Had Been For A Position A Person Was In

Tags: past-perfect

I want to express that if he does not do something he would lose his position he had been in but no longer is:

> "If you don't react, you will not regain the position you had been in
>   once"

(he can still react, so I use if clause 1 )

"had been" would indicate a relation to an earlier state, which he was in but then stopped being in. If I were to use ***"were in"*** it would indicate that he was in that situation once and he still may be in it.

Is that thinking correct?

Comment: I think it should be : If you don't react, you will not regain the position you were at once.

Comment: It's a little awkward, but not incorrect. Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: I think it should be "If you don't act, you will not regain the position you once had."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context, context, context!

*[In what follows I have changed your* BE in *a position to* HAVE *a position, because that is a bit more natural in this context. To* BE in *a position has the same sort of aspectual 'feel' as a progressive construction: it is not ordinarily used to speak of a situation whose endpoint lies inside the discourse timeframe.]*

Perfects are used to relate a prior eventuality to the time *which you are currently talking about*—this is sometimes called 'Reference Time' (RT).

In your example, your RT, the time you are talking about, is the 'non-past'—that is, you are talking about your hearer's present situation and what she should do from this point forward. Consequently, if you use a perfect at all it should be a **present perfect**, not a past perfect:

> <sup>?</sup> If you don't react, you will not regain the position you **have had**.

The <sup>?</sup>  marks this as only marginally acceptable. Why? . . .

Perfects express a state **at RT** which arises in some sense out of the prior eventuality. Now: it is a fact that your hearer held that job in the past, and it in another context it would be acceptable to say that she *has had the position*—for instance, if what you are talking about were her work experience (in fact, this use of the perfect is called by some authorities the *experiential perfect*). But that experience is not really relevant to your present discourse; what is relevant is not that she has had the position but that she does not have it now. You may properly use a present perfect to express that:

> If you don't react, you will not regain the position you **have lost**.

But if you want to refer specifically to her having held the position in the past, you should use a *simple past*, which signifies that the state lies completely in the past:

> If you don't react, you will not regain the position you **had**.